# How to record a video in Selenium webdriver and Java API

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, video-recording

I have automated scripts that run every night (around 50 scripts or testcases). I want to record a video of each test case (Selenium Java API + Cucumber). Is there any tool or way that i can use to control video recording for each test case separately? I want during a test case setup start recording and during teardown stop recording and save the video locally with a specified name and date. So I should have 50 videos for each testcase (more preferably save only videos for the failed test cases)

Is there a way of integrating this functionality in the code I use for my setups and teardowns?

Comment: take a look at saucelabs

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare, I know saucelabs, but I looking for a solution with Java API in my Jenkins or my Travis-ci (free solution).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find a solution [here](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.fr/2013/03/screen-recording-video-of-java-webdiver.html) but if you find better, you can post an other response:

```
org.monte.screenrecorder.ScreenRecorder  screenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder...
```

**Full main code:**

```
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.EncodingKey;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.FrameRateKey;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.KeyFrameIntervalKey;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.MIME_AVI;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.MediaTypeKey;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.MimeTypeKey;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.CompressorNameKey;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.DepthKey;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.QualityKey;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;

import org.monte.media.Format;
import org.monte.media.FormatKeys.MediaType;
import org.monte.media.math.Rational;
import org.monte.screenrecorder.ScreenRecorder;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class VideoReord {

    public static final String USER_DIR = "user.dir";
    public static final String DOWNLOADED_FILES_FOLDER = "downloadFiles";

    private ScreenRecorder screenRecorder;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        VideoReord videoReord = new VideoReord();
        videoReord.startRecording();

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("BreizhCamp 2018");
        element.submit();
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
        videoReord.stopRecording();
    }

    public void startRecording() throws Exception {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty(USER_DIR) + File.separator + DOWNLOADED_FILES_FOLDER);

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = screenSize.width;
        int height = screenSize.height;

        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

        GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();

        this.screenRecorder = new SpecializedScreenRecorder(gc, captureSize, new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
                new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE, CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE, DepthKey, 24, FrameRateKey,
                        Rational.valueOf(15), QualityKey, 1.0f, KeyFrameIntervalKey, 15 * 60),
                new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black", FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)), null, file, "MyVideo");
        this.screenRecorder.start();

    }

    public void stopRecording() throws Exception {
        this.screenRecorder.stop();
    }
}
```

**SpecializedScreenRecorder class extends ScreenRecorder class:**

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.monte.media.Format;
import org.monte.media.Registry;
import org.monte.screenrecorder.ScreenRecorder;

public class SpecializedScreenRecorder extends ScreenRecorder {

    private String name;

    public SpecializedScreenRecorder(GraphicsConfiguration cfg, Rectangle captureArea, Format fileFormat, Format screenFormat, Format mouseFormat, Format audioFormat, File movieFolder, String name)
            throws IOException, AWTException {
        super(cfg, captureArea, fileFormat, screenFormat, mouseFormat, audioFormat, movieFolder);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected File createMovieFile(Format fileFormat) throws IOException {
        if (!movieFolder.exists()) {
            movieFolder.mkdirs();
        } else if (!movieFolder.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IOException("\"" + movieFolder + "\" is not a directory.");
        }

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");

        return new File(movieFolder, name + "-" + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "." + Registry.getInstance().getExtension(fileFormat));
    }
}
```

Maven import:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
                <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- screen-recorder-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.monte</groupId>
        <artifactId>screen-recorder</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**CAUTION: If you use this on unix without GUI, you have this error:**

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

I look `Xvfb` plugin for Jenkins and Travis-ci and I re-edit this post.

**EDIT 1:**

If you use this on unix without GUI, you can use Jenkins + `Xvfb` plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not help you if you run tests via remote driver on selenium hub

Comment: @long how is it done for a remote driver ?

Comment: @mosaad I wish I know :)

Comment: It work only on same machine of webdriver (not work with selenium grid). This recording is on // of execution.

Comment: Added answer to record video for selenium test . Please refer   
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415669/screen-recording-of-a-test-execution-in-selenium-using-java/63829798#63829798

Comment: I executed this on a windows server VM and triggered the java program using jenkins. This results in a BLACK Screen video. Any idea why? @StéphaneGRILLON

Comment: @wishman, no sorry

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [this library](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/video-recorder-java) by Sergey Pirogov.

Comment: it works with selenium grid?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use either [Selenium-Grid-Extras](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras) or [Zalenium](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium).
Both are built on top of webdriver and do the recording automatically.